# How to enable tap-to-click (touchpad) on Awesome Window Manager between logins?

Tags: touchpad, awesome, tap-to-click

I am a Linux NOOB. Recently made the switch from Windows 10 and I am enjoying my Linux journey so far.

I just installed Awesome Window Manger recently. When I login to Awesome-WM for the first time, I found that my tap-to-click feature isn't working and it was irritating for me. So I used my googling skills and landed on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1527648/enable-track-pad-tapping-in-awesome-wm) link and the fix worked!

Unfortunately this thing is not persistent between my login sessions. I need to do this every time while logging into Awesome-WM.

Is there any permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Tapping and other touchpad settings are configured either through XInput2 as "device properties", or through Xorg.conf as settings for the 'libinput' driver.

Replace `Touchpad_Device_Name` with the device name (**not ID number**) that you see in `xinput list`.

`xinput set-prop "Touchpad_Device_Name" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`